# Elastica Search how to retrieve plain text results from indexed pdf/attachments

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

How do I get plain text search results from indexed pdf file contents with FOS Elastica Bundle?

I'm using
ElasticSearch with Attachment-Mapper Plugin
Elastica
FOS Elastica Bundle, with Doctrine on Symfony2

So far, I've been able to get the mapper-attachment up and running.  The pdf file content is indexed using this, https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/issues/96, as a guide.
Summary of method so you don't have to read the entire github post:

1) Creates a "document" entity with a "getEncodedFile" method.  Note: I only grab the file contents in this method.  I don't believe there is a need to base64 encode the data here as this happens later (I'm pretty sure the Elastica Document class does this).

2) Then I set up the config.yml:

```
      types: 
          document:  
                mappings:  
                    id: ~  
                    encodedFile:  
                        type: attachment
                persistence:
                    driver: orm 
                    model: MyBundle\Entity\Document
                    provider: ~
                    finder: ~
                    listener: ~
```

The search function returns the correct entity.  When I var_dump the hybrid results, I get the correct entity, including all the fields.  If I add the "setHighlight" method, nothing changes.  The setHighlight method returns nothing regarding the "encodedFile" field.  I did get setHighlight to work with other fields.

How do I pull the plain text search results (with some context) from the indexed base64 encoded data?

According to this stack post, [Best practices for searchable archive of thousands of documents (pdf and/or xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854858/best-practices-for-searchable-archive-of-thousands-of-documents-pdf-and-or-xml/10861308#10861308), it seems possible.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

So I caved.  I ended up using XPDF to extract and index the text of each pdf document.  Then I just run the query as normal.

Comment: does your query work if you run it via CURL on the command line? For an example of the notation see http://pastebin.com/ph8AbPU5

Comment: If I run the query in the command line, I get the same results that I get through the php, i.e. the correct results are produced but without plain text excerpt of the pdf contents.  It works as expected, but I would like to tease out the plain text excerpt of the pdf contents (stored as base64 encoded data).

Comment: can you post the json query? which version of Elastic Search are you using?